# Android GridView on click does not highlight

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

When I click on GridView item on image below it's item does not highlight.

How I can fix this?

[image]

I have tried this:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/GridView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/touch_listener"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:background="#000"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp" />
```

```
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"><color android:color="#99a8c038" />
</item>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"><color android:color="#99a8c038" />
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true"><color android:color="#99a8c038" />
</item>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"><color android:color="#00a8c038" />
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option must be using a "selector"

```
<GridView
...
...
android:listSelector="@drawable/my_grid__selector"
...
...>
</GridView>
```

inside your `res/drawable` folder create `my_grid__selector.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/yellow" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>    
</selector>
```

be sure to add the proeperty

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: I have edited my question, please take a look. It seems that doesnot work.

Comment: I tried your code, and it doesn't work in this situation. I don't knwo why.

Comment: add android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: It still doesn't work. I think image might be problem, because image is all over GridView item.